# refresh token rxjava+retrofir2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java

When registering in the application user gets 2 tokens. Access (lives 1 day) and Refresh (lives 6 months). At a certain point, the Access token will come-one day there will be a  custom error. At this , we need to call the refreshToken method and the updated , with which the work will go on.
We call the method, for example getdata , checking for  errors, if custom error  refreshToken  we keep both tokens  getdata already with the updated token.

i try but how to rerty call method getdata after refresh token?

```
mAllApi.getData(new Request().getRequestData())
           .flatMap(response -> {
               if (response.getError().equals(ECode.ERROR_TOKEN.getCode())) {
                     mAllApi.getRefreshToken(new String()).flatMap(new Function<AccessToken, ObservableSource<AccessToken>>() {
                        @Override
                        public ObservableSource<AccessToken> apply(AccessToken accessToken) throws Exception {
                           AccessTokenManager.saveNewAccessToken(accessToken);

                            return null;
                        }
                   });
               } else {
                   return Observable.just(response);
                }
           });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we did in our app - we created custom OkHttp Interceptor which checks for Access Token each time we do Auth Request and if it's corrupted Interceptor change it with RefreshToken, Add new updated value to Authorization Header and retries Request.
Here is example in Kotlin:

```
class RefreshAccessTokenInterceptor
@Inject constructor() : Interceptor {

    override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val response = chain.proceed(retryRequest(chain))
        return if (response.noAuthError()) {
            response
        } else {
            updateIfNeededOrProcessWithNewToken(chain)
        }
    }

    private fun retryRequest(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Request {
        val builder = chain.request().newBuilder()
        addAuthHeaders(builder)
        return builder.build()
    }

    private fun Response.noAuthError() = code() != HttpErrorChecker.HTTP_AUTHENTICATION_TIMEOUT

    private fun addAuthHeaders(builder: Request.Builder) {
        val accessToken = getAccessToken()
        if (!accessToken.isNullOrEmpty()) {
            builder.header("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
        }
    }

    private fun updateIfNeededOrProcessWithNewToken(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        //here you update your token, add new header and retries request

        return chain.proceed(retryRequest(chain))
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you refresh you token syncronously 
in `updateIfNeededOrProcessWithNewToke`. Do you use any RXJava logic to relogin in here?